# Partial derivative in x of $(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{2}{3}}$

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, solution-verification

Let $f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{2}{3}}$. Show that:

[image]

I did:

$$f'_x (x,y) = \frac{2}{3}(x^2+y^2)^{-\frac{1}{3}}*2x = \frac{4x}{3(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{1}{3}}}$$
At $(0;0):$

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(t;0)-f(0;0)}{t} = \lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{(t^2+0)^{2/3}-0}{t} = \\
\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{t^{4/3}}{t} = \lim_{t\rightarrow0}t^{1/3} = 0$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Your answer is right. Good job!

Comment: There's something ironic about marking as Correct Answer the one that tells me I'm right but hey, thanks

Comment: hahahahahahahaha